# Collections in dictionaries

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, collections

I would like to create a list of car makers with their models.
For this I'm using dictionary, where the key is the make and the item is a collection of models. For example:
The key in the dictionary is "Volkswagen" and the collection contains polo, cc, passat, etc...
The code reads the items from a worksheet. The problem is that I'm not sure that the collections are loaded with model types. Furthermore I checked debug options, how to write out the collection elements from the dictionaries, but I got empty messages. I'd be very happy if someone can help me fix this code.

```
Sub collectModels()

Dim imp_wb As Workbook, new_wb As Workbook
Dim ws_imp As Worksheet, ws_new As Worksheet, ws_stnd As Worksheet, ws_model_list As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim validate As String, model_key As String, model_item As String
Dim modelCollection As Collection


Set imp_wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws_model_list = imp_wb.Sheets("MODEL_LIST")

'Set new_wb = Workbooks.Add
'Set ws_new = new_wb.Worksheets(1)

Set rng = ws_stnd.Range("A2:A68")

'ws_imp.Activate
ws_model_list.Activate
lastRow = Last(1)
lastCol = Last(2)

Set dict_ModelMapping = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set modelCollection = New Collection


For i = 1 To lastCol

model_key = ws_model_list.Cells(1, i).Value

    For j = 2 To lastRow

        'add items to collection
        model_item = ws_model_list.Cells(j, i).Value


        If Not model_item = "" Then
            modelCollection.Add model_item
        Else
            'add collection to dictionary
            dict_ModelMapping.Add model_key, modelCollection
            Set modelCollection = New Collection
            GoTo nextColumn
        End If
    Next j

nextColumn:

'DEBUG CODE
    For Each v In dict_ModelMapping.Key("SUZUKI")
        Debug.Print v
    Next v
Next i


'--- CHECK COLLECTIONS---

Dim tmpCollection As Collection
Dim showItem As String

For Each Key In dict_ModelMapping.Keys

    MsgBox ("--------------" & Key & "---------------")


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Last`?

Comment: @SJR the Last is a function which returns the Last(1) last row , Last(2) last column , Last(3) last used cell in a worksheet. This was created by ron de burin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of:

- Creating a dictionary
- Creating collections and adding to dictionary with a key of `String`
- Iterating each item of the dictionary
- Printing the item in each collection that is dictionary value

You can adapt the sample code to suit your worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestDictionaryOfCollections()

    Dim dic As Object
    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim str As String
    Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant

    ' instantiate the dictionary
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' VW
    Set coll = New Collection
    coll.Add "Golf"
    coll.Add "Polo"
    coll.Add "Passat"
    coll.Add "Tiguan"
    dic.Add Item:=coll, Key:="VW"

    ' Ford
    Set coll = New Collection
    coll.Add "Fiesta"
    coll.Add "Falcon"
    coll.Add "Mondeo"
    coll.Add "Sierra"
    dic.Add Item:=coll, Key:="Ford"

    ' debug
    For Each var1 In dic.Keys
        For Each var2 In dic(var1)
            Debug.Print var2
        Next var2
    Next var1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected some things and taken liberties with others to get your code to work.  It's a good idea to use the option explicit directive as it helps with debugging:

```
Option Explicit


Sub collectModels()

  Dim imp_wb As Workbook
  Dim ws_model_list As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

  Dim model_key As String, model_item As String
  Dim modelCollection As Collection

  Set imp_wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws_model_list = imp_wb.Sheets("MODEL_LIST")

  With ws_model_list
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim dict_ModelMapping As Object
    Set dict_ModelMapping = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To lastCol
      model_key = .Cells(1, i).Value
      Set modelCollection = New Collection
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
      For j = 2 To lastRow
        'add items to collection
        model_item = .Cells(j, i).Value
        If model_item <> "" Then
          modelCollection.Add model_item
        End If
      Next j
      'add collection to dictionary
      dict_ModelMapping.Add model_key, modelCollection
    Next i

  End With

  'DEBUG CODE
  Dim v As Variant
  Dim coll As Collection
  Set coll = dict_ModelMapping("SUZUKI")
  For Each v In coll
    Debug.Print v
  Next v

  '--- CHECK COLLECTIONS---
  Dim key As Variant
  For Each key In dict_ModelMapping.Keys
    MsgBox ("--------------" & key & "---------------")
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I found 2 errors in the code. Loop j , has to contain an else in order to handle existing dictionary keys, because the rows are not consistent under each model. So when it reach an empty cell it has to jump to the next column.
The other error is the v loop. Run time rror '438' Object doesn't support this property or method. So basically it can't write out the collections. Any other idea?

Comment: I've moved the 'lastRow' line into the loop so that now it will properly find the last row of each column.  Also I've explicitly set the value of the dictionary to a collection so that now that loop will print out each item in the collection.   the 'Set coll' sets a reference to the collection (note that we're not using 'new') so that coll points to it.  Now you should be able to iterate through the collection for 'SUZUKI' properly.  Let me know whether this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to handle empty cells. As soon as a list is over, then the code saves the dictionary with the collection. To refer to the collection inside the dictionary you have to create a loop inside a loop.

```
ws_model_list.Activate
lastRow = Last(1)
lastCol = Last(2)

Set dict_ModelMapping = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For i = 1 To lastCol

model_key = ws_model_list.Cells(1, i).Value
Set modelCollection = New Collection
    For j = 2 To lastRow

        'add items to collection
        model_item = ws_model_list.Cells(j, i).Value

        If model_item <> "" Then
            modelCollection.Add model_item
        Else
            'add collection to dictionary
            dict_ModelMapping.Add Key:=model_key, Item:=modelCollection
            GoTo nextColumn
        End If

    Next j

nextColumn:

Next i



Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    For Each v1 In dict_ModelMapping.Keys
        For Each v2 In dict_ModelMapping(v1)
            MsgBox (v2)
        Next v2
   Next v1
```